# Space between word affect Google Search results

Tags: seo, google-search

I am little bit confused that if I add space between my brand name then how it will effect the ranking.

For example my brand name is *BigV* but some how people search for *Big V* and Google showing different result.

So is there any solution for this results?

Answer (score 0):

Over time your brand will be associated with both results. Search engines are treating your brand name as one word since that's how it's displayed on your site and domain. I can't think of any examples to show you though. But I have seen it before. Good backlinks to both versions would be a good start.

Comment: Thanks Charlie for the reply, but whenever i tried to use my Brand name without space google showing search result with "Did you mean", so how will I get rid of these result?

Comment: Hey Deepika, Have you had any progress with your SEO problem? Hope all is well!